# Properly keeping track of which (nested) div has mouse-over

Tags: javascript, html, mouseover, mousemove, nested

I have a (deeply) nested structure of `<div>`s. With Javascript, I'd like to keep track of which element the mouse is currently over (i.e., 'has focus'), where more deeply nested elements have priority:

[image: Desired mouse-over behavior in nested divs]

I've tried combinations of `mouseover`, `mouseout`, `mouseenter`, `mouseleave` and `mousemove`, but there seems to be no simple solution that gives me the expected behavior. I am able to receive mouse-events on the right divs, but often these events are subsequently received by higher level divs, which would then undeservedly take focus.

For example, in the transition above from `a` to `c`, the event might then be received by `b` last, unintentionally giving focus to `b` rather than `c`. Or the transition from `c` to `b` might not be registered at all for some reason.

I don't understand the underlying mechanism of mouse-event propagation well enough to come up with a reliable solution. It seems like it should be such a simple thing, but I can't figure it out.

I've been able to get it to work as follows: when a div receives a `mouseenter`/`over` event, flag it and search the entire DOM subtree. If any other flags are found deeper down, relinquish focus. But this is rather crude, and I can't help but think there must be an easier way.

#### Edit: Solution

The use of `mouseover` and `mouseout`, combined with a call to  `stopPropagation()` seems to work very well. Here is a [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mhelvens/BH593/) to show the working solution.

Comment: Thanks for this. I was struggling with a similar problem. Your solution helped.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the event `stopPropagation()` method:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/event.stopPropagation

If using jQuery, try calling `stopPropagation()` on the event passed as the first parameter

http://api.jquery.com/event.stoppropagation/

```
$( "p" ).on('mouseover', function( event ) {
  event.stopPropagation();
  // Do something
});
```

Also, you can check which element is the target, as in `event.target`.

Comment: This is a vanilla method https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/event.stopPropagation

Comment: Thanks, updated the answer. Sorry for falling into jQuery before Vanella JS.

Comment: Thanks! Using `stopPropagation` in the right way is the piece of the puzzle I was missing. :-) It doesn't work with `mouseenter`, though. I had to use `mouseover` to make it work properly. Here is a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mhelvens/BH593/) to show my working code. Perhaps you could adjust your answer. In fact, it would help enormously if you could explain why `mouseover` does the trick here, while `mouseenter` does not. --- Cheers!

Comment: Thanks. Adjusted answer. My random guess might be that mouseenter happens so quickly that it happens for the out DVI first, while the browser might be waiting a bit for mouseover. Something like this happens with swipe and click in mobile browsers, where the browser tries to solve by waiting 300ms before firing the click in case you were clicking to start a swipe or so.

Answer (score 1):

For non-IE browsers & IE >= 9 use,

```
    evt.stopPropagation();
```

For Legacy IE browsers(IE<9) browsers use,

```
    evt.cancelBubble = true;
```

This will prevent bubbling of events to parent elements.